# Compile a header to executable in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Suppose I have a dual purpose header that can be used as either a header or a source file controlled by a preprocessor switch `AS_CPP`. It is possible to use the command `g++ -x c++ -DAS_CPP foo.h -o foo` to compile it into a executable.

Is it possible to achieve this in CMake in a cross-platform way (without explicitly writing out the command)?

---

Failed attempt:

```
...
add_executable(foo EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL foo.h)
set_source_files_properties(foo.h PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-x c++")
set_target_properties(eqtb PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

This only made CMake to link immediately without compiling first.

Comment: I imagine this is _possible_, but I'd actually say that this approach is not exactly _wise_ to do. If this header gets included in more than one place, then you'll immediately hit an ODR violation. It would be more coherent to instead require the consumer to include the header into a source file that _they_ compile with a different definition to ensure it only generates the symbols exactly once.

Comment: @Human-Compiler, fair point. My case is that I have a huge `enum` - the header basically has a `int main(...)` that converts between enumerator names and values, and `main` is defined only if `AS_CPP` is defined. I imagine ODR is not a problem in this case. But sure I can just make a separate source file.

Comment: Imagine someone include this header and compile it with `AS_CPP` defined. It seems like a promising arrow in someone's knee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the file to a proper suffix.

```
add_custom_command(
    COMMENT "Copying foo.h to foo.cpp"
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cpp
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.h
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cpp
)
add_executable(foo ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.cpp)
```

Answer (score 1):

> My case is that I have a huge enum - the header basically has a int main(...) that converts between enumerator names and values, and main is defined only if AS_CPP is defined.

Simple solution to the XY-problem: Don't define `main` in the header at all. Define it in another file that you name using a more conventional suffix.